Why is Prometheus returning "HTTP status 503 Service Unavailable" when scraping my .NET Core microservice `/health_metrics` endpoint?
I'm facing an issue with Prometheus while trying to scrape metrics from my .NET Core microservice. I’ve got my service running in Docker, and I can access the /health_metrics endpoint just fine through my browser at http://192.168.161.74:2011/health_metrics. It displays metrics without any issue.

However, Prometheus is returning a 503 Service Unavailable error when attempting to scrape this endpoint. Here’s a snippet of my prometheus.yml configuration:
global:
  scrape_interval: 15s

scrape_configs:

  - job_name: 'health-metrics'
    metrics_path: /health_metrics
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['192.168.161.74:2011']

Additional Information:

My microservice setup includes various tools and dashboards like:

GraphQL Client Tools: Portal Banana, Portal Voyager, Adaptor Banana, Adaptor Voyager
REST Client Tools: Swagger
Hangfire Dashboard
Health Check: Health UI, Health API


The /health_metrics endpoint is accessible via browser and shows metrics such as GC collection count, process start time, memory usage, etc.


Here is a sample of the metrics exposed by /health_metrics:
# HELP dotnet_collection_count_total GC collection count
# TYPE dotnet_collection_count_total counter
dotnet_collection_count_total{generation="1"} 0
dotnet_collection_count_total{generation="0"} 1
dotnet_collection_count_total{generation="2"} 0

# HELP process_start_time_seconds Start time of the process since unix epoch in seconds.
# TYPE process_start_time_seconds gauge
process_start_time_seconds 1721278066.591546
...

Troubleshooting steps I’ve tried so far:

Verified that the endpoint is accessible from the Prometheus server.(from inside and outside)
Ensured there are no firewall rules blocking traffic between Prometheus and the microservice.
Checked Docker logs for any errors, but found none related to the /health_metrics endpoint.


Questions for the community:

What could be causing Prometheus to return a 503 Service Unavailable error when the endpoint is accessible via a browser?
Are there specific configurations in Prometheus or Docker that might need adjustment to resolve this issue?
Could there be any resource constraints or timeout settings causing this behavior?
Is there a way to get more detailed logging from Prometheus to diagnose the root cause of this issue?

I tested this issue on Windows for my .NET Core microservices, and this error occurs there as well. I created a code using Golang to get this content from /health_metrics for Prometheus and shown /metric in another port, and it worked, which makes me think the delay might be the problem.
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

What OS? Are Prometheus and the .NET service on the same machine? Is Prometheus running in a container? Is the .NET service using TLS? Self-signed cert?

I tested both setups: first with the .NET service and Prometheus in Docker on the same machine, then on Windows as a service with IIS, using HTTP. We installed the service for our customer with HTTPS, but there are no self-signed certificates. Now we want to create Grafana dashboards. I wrote a Go app to read http://localhost:port/health_metrics and serve it at http://localhost:anotherport/metrics for Prometheus. However, I'm encountering a 503 error when Prometheus tries to connect

Prometheus returning "HTTP 503 Service Unavailable" while scraping your .NET Core /health_metrics endpoint can occur due to misconfigured Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) policies. Adding the /health_metrics endpoint to your CORS configuration resolved the issue.
Here’s how to fix it in your .NET Core app:
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowPrometheus", builder =>
    {
        builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:9090")
               .AllowAnyMethod()
               .AllowAnyHeader();
    });
});
app.UseCors("AllowPrometheus");

After restarting the service with the updated CORS configuration, Prometheus successfully scraped the metrics.
Other Troubleshooting Tips AI Suugested:

Ensure the /health_metrics endpoint has the Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8.
Check response times to ensure they fall within Prometheus’ timeout limits.
Use Prometheus logs to diagnose scraping issues.


This concise answer focuses on the CORS fix and highlights other potential causes for similar issues.
